# Style sheet still displaying the underline in a button div after text: decoration is set to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a div that I turned into a button by placing `<a href="#"></a>` around it. The text inside the button is currently showing an underline.

CSS

```
.button-link:hover {

        text-decoration: none;

    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="button-container" id="button-container-three">

                <a href="#">
                    <div class="button-div button-link" id="button-three">
                    <br>
                    <h1>Lorum Ipsem</h1>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
```

I want to remove the underline from the occurring when I hover.

I have this done to two other buttons on the page and the result is what I want it to be (no underline under the text when I hover) but this button is still showing the underline.

I fixed it by adding the class to the `<a></a>` tags instead as seen below.

```
<div class="button-container" id="button-container-three">

                <a class="button-link" href="#">
                    <div class="button-div" id="button-three">
                    <br>
                    <h1>Lorum Ipsem</h1>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
```

But my question is: why was this not necessary with the other two buttons? I did not edit their text decorations at all, see the code below:

```
<div class="button-container">

                <a href="#">                    
                    <div class="button-div" id="button-one">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h1>Lorum Ipsem</h1></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="button-div" id="button-two">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h1>Lorum Ipsem</h1></div>
                </a>


            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could target the `a` element instead...

```css
.button-container a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container" id="button-container-three">

  <a href="#">
    <div class="button-div button-link" id="button-three">
      <br>
      <h1>Lorum Ipsem</h1>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="button-container" id="button-container-three">
    <a href="#" class="class="button-div button-link" id="button-three">
    <h1>Lorum Ipsem</h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

The text-decoration attribute gets applied to the anchor tag by default, not the . I would suggest restructuring your code to how I have in my example. The inner div you had set seems unnecessary for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: "The inner div you had set seems unnecessary for what you are trying to accomplish." but wouldn't  this set the text to be the link rather than the whole div? I set the link to surround an inner div because I want it to highlight and do other things of that nature. Wouldn't setting the link around the <h1> stop this from being possible?